# Trouble with getting an alt in html with javascript to change a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I [have](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MajoWR) at the moment. This is for my introduction to Computer Programming. What I want is for the hover to say "from country, Hello World!" like here

```
var alt = document.getElementById("picture")[0].alt;
    if (alt=="usa") {
        country = "United States";
    } else if(alt=="ecu"){
        country = "Ecuador";
    }else if(alt == "hai"){
        country = "Haiti";
    }else{
        country = "Turkey";
    }
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "from " + country + ", Hello World!";
```

Either i'm doing it wrong or need direction to a better(maybe easier?) way to do this, it doesn't matter if my whole code needs changed. I'm stumped. I've tried w3schools and a couple other sites, along with my book but i'm not understanding how to do this.. Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: `var alt = document.getElementById("picture")[0].alt;` <--<< Why is there a `[0]` in there?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Working code from your example:

```
function away() {
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
}

function clicked(url, alt) {
  document.getElementById("picture").src = url;
  document.getElementById("picture").alt = alt;
  document.getElementById("picture").style.height = "116px";
  document.getElementById("picture").style.width = "220px";

}

function hover() {
  var country;
  var alt = document.getElementById("picture").alt;
  console.log('alt', alt)
  if (alt === "usa") {
    country = "United States";
  } else if (alt === "ecu") {
    country = "Ecuador";
  } else if (alt === "hai") {
    country = "Haiti";
  } else {
    country = "Turkey";
  }
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = ("from " + country + ", Hello World!");
}

document.getElementById("picture").addEventListener('mouseenter', hover);
document.getElementById("picture").addEventListener('mouseleave', away);
```

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/miguelmota/pen/epdRmq**

Comment: Thank you! Got it working now. I'm going to have to read up on EventListeners, thanks! :)

Comment: No prob! and Downvoter, mind explaining how this fails to answer OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map:

```
var countries = {
    usa: "United States",
    ecu: "Ecuador",
    hai: "Haiti",
    defaultCountry: "Turkey"
};

alt = document.getElementById("picture")[0].alt; // Is [0] correct?
country = countries.hasOwnProperty(alt) ? countries[alt] : countries.defaultCountry;

document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "from " + country + ", Hello world!";
```

This way you avoid all the `if/else if` in the code and to add a country, you would only need to add it to the `countries` object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I tried putting that into the codepen but it is still not coming up into the 2nd column of the table whenever I hover into it..

Comment: This rewrites a working part of the question while leaving the problem code intact.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns an HTML element. It doesn't return an array or anything array-like. HTML elements do not have a `0` property.

Remove the `[0]`.

Comment: Removing the `[0]` made the code working, but all of the if statements are false and the else statement is the one executing.

Comment: @EvanTheis — Your question is missing any HTML so it is hard to tell why. If we look on the site you linked to: `<img onmouseover='hover()' onmouseout="away()" id="picture">` - There is no alt attribute, so I don't know why you would expect it to match any of the if statements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't save the codepen. Got it fixed now, thanks for all your guys' help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `[0]` implies that you want to access the first element of an array (or a `NodeList`).  However, `document.getElementById()` does not return an array, it returns an `Element`.  On the other hand, a method like `document.getElementsByClassName()` would return a `NodeList` that you could access similar to an array.

I'm a big security guy and I push good security practices whenever I can.  When you write something like `document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML = '<strong>woohoo</strong';`, for example, you assume that:

1. An element with ID #someElement exists in `document`
2. That `document.getElementById()` will return an `Element`, which has the property innerHTML.  (of course, in this case this is always true.)

I just want to recommend that you never trust data received by your functions.  Always validate that the data you're about to manipulate was actually passed (it's not `undefined`) and that it's the type you'd expect (such as `number`, `string`, `Element`, etc.)

I'd also recommend using a `switch` statement instead of all those if/else statements.  Consider the following snippet:

```
var picture = document.getElementById("picture");
var country = ''; // declare as a string
var message = document.getElementById("msg");

if (! (picture instanceof Element) || ! (message isntanceof Element) ) 
    return; // couldn't find the elements we need

switch (picture.alt.toLowerCase()) { // use toLowerCase() for robustness
    case 'usa':
        country = 'United States';
        break;
    case 'ecu':
        country = 'Ecuador';
        break;
    case 'hai':
        country = 'Haiti';
        break;
    default:
        country = 'Turkey';
}

message.textContent = "from " + country + ", Hello World!";
```